# SCanvasView grid

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to display 4 ScanvasView, per default on SDK 3 ScanvasView displays verticaly.
I don't know how do you do that with RelativeLayout or LinearLayout.

I would to display 2 ScanvasView horizontal and 2 below as:

```
         ImageView1
ScanvasView1      ScanvasView2
ScanvasView3     ScanvasView4
          TextView
         ImageView2
```

How do you do that? Thank you.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingLeft="70dip"
android:paddingRight="70dip"
android:background="@drawable/fond_pages">  
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/canvas_container1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"     
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <com.samsung.spensdk.SCanvasView 
        android:id="@+id/canvas_view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/canvas_container2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    <com.samsung.spensdk.SCanvasView 
        android:id="@+id/canvas_view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/canvas_container3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    <com.samsung.spensdk.SCanvasView 
        android:id="@+id/canvas_view3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a 9x9 grid and I just use a single SCanvasView.  You can get co-ordinates and other information from the SCanvasView that will let you calculate where on the screen the pen has made gestures.